# BindException during binding data in form

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/product/new")
public String newProduct(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("cat", categoryService.getAllCategoriesCommand());
    model.addAttribute("productf", new ProductCommand());
    return "product/addProduct";
}

 @PostMapping("product")
public String saveNewProduct(@ModelAttribute("productf") ProductCommand productCommand, Model model) {
    productService.saveCommand(productCommand);
    return "redirect:/index";
}
```

Form:

```
      <tr th:each="category : ${cat}">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="" th:value="${category.id}" th:text="${category.categoryName}" th:field="*{categories}"/>
            </label>
        </div>
```

Domain/Command classes:

```
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "categories")
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String name;
private String description;
private BigDecimal price;
private String manufacturer;
private Long unitsInStock;
private boolean discontinued;
private Byte[] image;

//@ElementCollection
//private Map<String, String> productProperties = new HashMap<>();

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(name = "product_category",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_id"))
private Set<Category> categories = new HashSet<>();
}
```

ProductCommand class:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ProductCommand {

private Long id;
private String name;
private String description;
private BigDecimal price;
private String manufacturer;
private Long unitsInStock;
private boolean discontinued;
private Byte[] image;
private Set<CategoryCommand> categories = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Category class:

```
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "products")
public class Category  {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String categoryName;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories")
private Set<Product> products; 
}
```

CategoryCommand class:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CategoryCommand {

private Long id;
private String categoryName;
}
```

And when I want submit the form I got below error:

```
Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors Field error in object 'productf' on field 'categories': rejected value [1]; codes [typeMismatch.productf.categories,typeMismatch.categories,typeMismatch.java.util.Set,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [productf.categories,categories]; arguments []; default message [categories]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Set' for property 'categories'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'info.mike.webstorev1.commands.CategoryCommand' for property 'categories[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

I don't know why Spring cannot convert String, I don't see any Strings there. And when I (in controller) pass to to the model New Product and categoryService.getAllCategories() instead of New ProductCommand and categoryService.getAllCategoriesCommand() it all works very well with no exceptions. I am asking for help.

Edited:

```
   @Transactional
@Override
public ProductCommand saveCommand(ProductCommand productCommand) {
    Product detachedProduct = productCommandToProduct.convert(productCommand);
    Product savedProduct = productRepository.save(detachedProduct);
    return productToProductCommand.convert(savedProduct);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register a custom editor on the binder so you can convert a String to a Server instance. There is an example of a custom PropertyEditor [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion-customeditor-registration) in the Spring reference docs that should get you started.

Comment: But from where is string there ? When I put to the model New Product instead New ProductCommand it all works great without any custom editor ; <

Comment: And I also created converter classes like ProductToProductCommand and vice versa which implements Converter<S,T> interface.

Comment: public String saveNewProduct() << what is it returning?

Comment: it returns "redirect:/index", but methotd inside looks like this: I edited the post.